# Handling biometrics authentication

Tags: react-native, biometrics

I was wondering how to handle a Biometric authentication (fingerPrint, Face ID) on mobile APP using React Native.

Indeed, it's easy to use the captor but the back-end architecture is missing for me.

After authentication, I need a token from my API to continue passing HTTP request with an Authorization header. And this token is only send after an authentication request (username/password).

What is the most secure to authenticate a user with this architecture ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to use biometric auth but also pass a token with the HTTP request?

Comment: I would like to use biometric as a password to use the same HTTP request whate ever the user used the biometric or a classic password. This request will return an authorization token.

Comment: As far as I understand the biometric authentication data is always stored on the device and has nothing to do with what will be sent in the HTTP request.